# type error: cannot call method 'invoke procedure' of undefined in worklight

Tags: adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

this is my js function...

```
var invocationData={
                adapter : 'Health_Care',
                procedure: 'update',
                    parameters:[uname,cp,np]
            };

            WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,
            {
                onSuccess: function(){
                     alert("Password successfully changed");
                },
                  onFailure: function(){
                      alert("failed");
                  }

            }       
            );
```

my adapter is...

```
var updateStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET PASSWORD=? WHERE UID=? AND PASSWORD=?");
```

function update(pid,curP,newP) {

```
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : updateStatement,
    parameters : [newP,pid,curP]

});
```

}

my adapter is alone working when i invoke adapter... but with java script i'm getting the above mentioned error for all the pages....

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're trying to use Worklight features in other HTML pages without having all the required script tags (`worklight.js`, `wlclient.js`, etc.). Worklight is geared towards single page applications, if you want multiple HTML files make sure all the right JavaScript is getting loaded (look at the native folder, `www/default/[appname].html` in the head tag).

Here's an example: **native/www/default/wlapp.html**

```
<!-- Static App properties + WL namespace definition -->
<script src="wlclient/js/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="common/js/wljq.js"></script>
<script src="common/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="wlclient/js/messages.js"></script>
<script src="common/js/wlcommon.js"></script>
<script src="wlclient/js/diagnosticDialog.js"></script>
<script src="wlclient/js/deviceAuthentication.js"></script>
<script src="wlclient/js/window.js"></script>
<script src="wlclient/js/worklight.js"></script>
<script src="wlclient/js/wlclient.js"></script>
<!-- More script tags... -->
```

The JavaScript file that defines WL.Client.invokeProcedure is `wlclient/js/wlclient.js`.