# Error facing while invoking WL.Client.invokeProcedure

Tags: iphone, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am invoking a worklight adapter and making restful call to external service. While executing worklight method `WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,options)` getting below error on debug area:

> 'null' is not a valid argument for 'in'"

Below is my adapter call implementation not sure where I'm making mistake.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/_base/xhr",
     "dojo/_base/json", "dojo/_base/Deferred"], 
         function(declare,lang,xhr,json,Deferred) {

     return {
            mobGetLocationLatLng: function(pAddress) {          

                   console.log("+++adapter1.mobGetLocationLatLng+++pAddress" +
     pAddress );

         try{
            var invocationData = {
                    adapter : 'GeoCode',
                    procedure : 'getGmapLatLng',
                    parameters : [pAddress]
                    };

            console.log("+++about to invoke procedure+++"+ JSON.stringify(invocationData)); 
            WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
                onSuccess : this.gMapLatLngSuccess,
                onFailure : this.gMapLatLngFailure
            });
        }
        catch (e){
            console.log('Error...:' + e.message);
        }

    },
    gMapLatLngSuccess: function (result){
        console.log('Success:');
        console.log('<<<<<adapter1.result>>>>>>>>> ' + JSON.stringify(result.invocationResult));
        return result.invocationResult;
    },
    gMapLatLngFailure: function(){
        console.log('Failure');
    }
  };
});
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Test 1: Prove the Adapter Works in isolation (no JavaScript)

Try right clicking the GeoCode adapter folder > Deploy Adapter > Invoke Procedure > ...

Does it work? Do you get back what you expect?

#### Test 2: Prove the Adapter Call works in isolation (JavaScript)

Try creating a new Hybrid Worklight Application (wlapp) under your existing Worklight Project (that has access to the GeoCode adapter) > Open `wlapp.js` > Replace all the code inside with the following:

```
function wlCommonInit () {

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
        adapter : 'GeoCode',
        procedure : 'getGmapLatLng',
        parameters : ['hardcode_valid_value_here']
        },{
        onSuccess : function(res){ console.log('win', res); },
        onFailure : function(res){ console.log('fail', res); }
    });
}
```

**Note:** `'hardcode_valid_value_here'` should be replaced with a valid value.

Try to **isolate the issue**, seems like you just copy/pasted code from your app without trying to isolate the error.

Does it work? Do you get back what you expect?

#### Test 3: Prove no issues with Worklight script tags

If you're using multiple HTML pages, [take a look at this StackOverflow reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15631445/186909). If you have everything inside a single HTML page, does it work?

#### Test 4: Try the Debugger

Open Google Chrome > Open the WL Console (localhost:8080/console) > Preview as Common Resources > [Add a Break Point](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints) to the `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` call > Make sure that code gets executed and stops at the Break Point > Keep Stepping into / Traversing the code. Share the code that causes the issue.

#### Update your question with more information based on the tests above.

#### Other way to write the code

```
function wlCommonInit () {

//Define your LocationSingleton under myNameSpace
var myNameSpace = myNameSpace || {};
myNameSpace.LocationSingleton = (function ($) {

        //Private Members:
        var _getLocationFromAdapter = function (pAddress) {

            var deferred = $.Deferred(),

                    invocationData = {
                        adapter : 'GeoCode',
                        procedure : 'getGmapLatLng',
                        parameters : [pAddress]
                    },

                    success = function (res) {
                        console.log('Worked:', res);
                        deferred.resolve(res);
                    },

                    failure = function (err) {
                        console.log('Failed:', err);
                        deferred.reject(err);
                    };

                    console.log('Calling getLocationFromAdapter with:', invocationData);
                    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
                        onSuccess : success,
                        onFailure : failure
                    });

                    return deferred.promise();
        };

        //Public API:
        return {
            getLocationFromAdapter : _getLocationFromAdapter
        };

}(WLJQ));


        //Usage: Calling the function and getting the location or a failure
        myNameSpace.LocationSingleton.getLocationFromAdapter('hardcode_valid_value_here')

        .then(function (res) {
            console.log('Done:', res);
        })

        .fail(function (err) {
            console.log('Err:', err);
        });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, test1 and test2 i have tested separately and found no issues...The adapter is working fine individually and adapter is calling is also working individually(tested this by removing all the code and just kept the code for invoking adapter). I think the problem is in my project code not in the adapter. Earlier it was not throwing error in chrome but now getting the error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'SUPPORT_COOKIES' in null".

Comment: Are you waiting until `wlCommonInit()` function is called? I updated my answer with an example that does what you want and is modular. I didn't test it, but it may give you ideas. I don't know Dojo, hence the lack of Dojo in my example.

Comment: Thanks this helps, actually WL.Client.init was not invoking from initOptions.js not sure why so if changed below code from 
**********old************
if (window.addEventListener) {
 window.addEventListener('load', function() { WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); }, false);
} 
*******New******
Thanks this helps, actually WL.Client.init was not invoking from initOptions.js not sure why so if changed below code from 
**********old************
if (window.addEventListener) {
 window.addEventListener('load',WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions), false);
}

Comment: If the answer was helpful you should click un the up arrow =]