# How to pass data between pages through worklight client API

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to invoke a procedure in one page and use it in another page, and the response is only used by the next page, so I think JsonStore is not suit for that. Should I define a global var?
   Is there any code sample to do such things? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume by pages you mean different HTML files. If so, that is not recommended, [Worklight is intended for single page applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15631445/186909). There are no code samples that show how to do that.

I would recommended having a single HTML page and using something like [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to inject new HTML / DOM elements. By dynamically injecting new HTML your single/main HTML file shouldn't be too big and you can destroy (i.e. remove from memory / the DOM) unused DOM elements. Searching on Google for `page fragments` and `html templates` could help you find examples. The idea is that you don't lose the JavaScript context.

Maybe you can get away with doing a new [init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_init.html) to re-initialize JSONStore (it won't delete any the data, just give you access) on every new HTML page and use [get](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_jsonstore_get.html) to get access to the JSONStore collections to perform operations such as [find](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_find.html).